# How to build peer-to-peer connection through internet in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I build local network (localhost, in my own PC) using Docker in Hyperledger Fabric.
But how can I realize peer-to-peer connection through internet (like torrent) in Hyperledger Fabric ?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to use either of these:

1. [Hyperledger Fabric deployment script](https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment) - bash script which spans network on bare metals
2. [Ansible Playbooks](https://github.com/litong01/fabric-deploy) to deploy Hyperledger Fabric

There is good [documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) on how to get started and for any particular question you can try asking in [Rocket.Chat](http://chat.hyperledger.org).